# iOS CoreBluetooth scanForPeripherals() not showing device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, rfcomm

I need to connect to a device in my iOS app using Bluetooth in order to fetch data. The app is developed using Flutter SDK, but for this specific task I decided to go native.
The device from which I want to fetch data is a Raspberry Pi 3 and it runs a RFCOMM server (or at least this is what is written in the documentation). I didn't choose this protocol, when I joined the project it had already been developed.

Here comes the strange part of the story. When I launch the scan from the Bluetooth section of my iPhone's Settings app, I'm able to see the device and to successfully connect with it; instead, when I launch the scan from the code that you see below, I can't find the device. And what's more, if I use a 3rd party app for scanning Bluetooth devices nearby (and for retrieving data such as identifier, rssi, service ids, etc.), the Raspberry doesn't show up in the list.

What trick is this? Why does Apple let you find a device from Settings app and not from its own Bluetooth API, which it is supposed to use also in the Settings app?

Here's the code that I use for scanning:

```
import CoreBluetooth
    ...
    @UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
  private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let bluetoothChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "my.app.bluetooth.channel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    bluetoothChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
        [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
        guard call.method == "scanBluetoothDevices" else {
            result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
            return
        }
        self?.scanBluetoothDevices(result: result)
    })
    
    ...
  }
...
private func scanBluetoothDevices(result: FlutterResult) {
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}
...
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("Peripheral: \(peripheral)")
    }
    
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    var consoleMsg = ""
        
    switch (central.state) {
    case .poweredOff:
        consoleMsg = "BLE is powered off"
    case .poweredOn:
        consoleMsg = "BLE is powered on"
        let options: [String: Any] = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:
                                      NSNumber(value: false)]
        centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: options)
    ...
    @unknown default:
        consoleMsg = "BLE is in unhandled state"
    }
        
    print("\(consoleMsg)")
}
```

Comment: Core Bluetooth gives no access to RFCOMM directly. It primarily handles BLE, and recently it's added L2CAP, and even more recently GATT over BR/EDR (but just GATT, no other profiles). MFi licensed devices can communicate with iAP2. But if you're only communicating with RFCOMM, you won't see it.